# Scrolling the label

Tags: python, label, scrollview, kivy

I'm writing small aplication for myself and I have some trouble with it.
I can't scrolling label using ScrollView. Label appears by reading text file.

I show a part of my code.

.py code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

class GeneralForm(TabbedPanel):
    txt_show = ObjectProperty()

    def SHOW_CONTENT(self):
        FILE=open('data')
        A=FILE.read()
        self.txt_show.text=A

class TimeTable(App):

    def build(self):
        return GeneralForm()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TimeTable().run()
```

.kv code:

```
<GeneralForm>:
    do_default_tab: False
    txt_show:txt1
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Mon'
        on_release: root.SHOW_CONTENT()
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            ScrollView:
                size: self.size
                Label:
                    id:txt1
                    text: ''
                    size_hint_y: None
            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    text: 'Edit'
                Button:
                    text: 'Exit'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Tue'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Wed'
```

"data" file is a simple txt file with a lot of lines of the text.
When that text are showing in the Label - it's truncated.

How can I add scroll for the text in label?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ScrollView:
    Label:
        id:txt1
        text: ''
        text_size: self.width, None  # Set the text wrap box width
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]  # Set the Label height to the text height
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was helped.

Answer (score 0):

go to the site https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel and download.
Copy the .m and the .h file to your project and add the quartz core framework.
Go to your .h file and import the marquee.h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MarqueeLabel.h"

@interface PlayerViewController : UIViewController
```

Then create a label in the UIViewController then drag it to the .h file with the ctrl pressed. Stay with the outlet option, write the name of the label you want, change the UILabel to MarqueeLabel.
it will be like that:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MarqueeLabel *nomeMusicaLabel;
```

Select the label in the view, go to the utilities bar in the right of the screen, go to the identity inspector (the third button), change the class to MarqueeLabel.

Go to your .m file and write this code:

```
nomeMusicaLabel.text = @"Write your text here";
self.nomeMusicaLabel.marqueeType = MLContinuous;
self.nomeMusicaLabel.scrollDuration = 15.0;
self.nomeMusicaLabel.animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut;
self.nomeMusicaLabel.fadeLength = 10.0f;
self.nomeMusicaLabel.leadingBuffer = 30.0f;
self.nomeMusicaLabel.trailingBuffer = 20.0f;
```

Inside the MarkeeLabel zip file, there is  project with many other types of scrool texts.